# DAX Nesting Multiple IF statements

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have 3 IF statements, each in a separate column...

```
Column 1 = IF(RELATED(dim_verification_measure5[measure_check_type])="min",IF([measure_value]<RELATED(dim_verification_measure5[measure_target_value_min]),20,10))
Column 2 = IF(RELATED(dim_verification_measure5[measure_check_type])="max",IF([measure_value]>RELATED(dim_verification_measure5[measure_target_value_min]),20,10))
Column 3 = IF(RELATED(dim_verification_measure5[measure_check_type])="between",IF([measure_value]>RELATED(dim_verification_measure5[measure_target_value_min]),IF([measure_value]<RELATED(dim_verification_measure5[measure_target_value_max]),20,10)))
```

The resulting value in each column is correct.

[image]

However, I would like the see all of the values in the same column. Is it possible to nest all of these IF statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but instead of nesting if statements which are difficult to read, we use the following:

```
SWITCH(TRUE(), 
value, result,
value, result,
else)
```

Alternatively, use COALESCE() on your existing 3 statements.

Comment: Please replace else with result!

Comment: What do you mean? That is exactly how it is described in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/switch-function-dax

Comment: SWITCH(<expression>, <value>, <result>[, <value>, <result>]…[, <else>])

Comment: @DavidBacci - I used the COALESCE() method. Much neater than a lengthy nested statement. Thank you.